# How to change the sequence id and relation in the table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to increase `id` by 1000. I already have records in the tables. I create migration:

```
def change
  execute("ALTER SEQUENCE orders_id_seq START WITH 1000")
end
```

But in other tables there is a relation `order_id`. I need to increase them too?

How can I increase them to 1000?

Comment: Do you already have some records present?

Comment: If the sequence of orders relation is changed it will take id from orders table only

Comment: You don't need to change order_id in every relation

Comment: with `alter sequence` you dont increase any `id` - you set the start value of sequence

Comment: Yes, i have record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't increase anything but value of sequence start with your command. if you want that value to become nextval, you have to use `RESTART` instead (see example below). Also - when you set nextval for sequence, you only change next DEFAULT value for `id`, not previous `id` values. To increase all values of column `id`, you have to run smth like `update relation set id=id+1000;`

below is example what your statement does:

```
t=# \x
Expanded display is on.
t=# create table so14(i bigserial);
CREATE TABLE
t=# select * from so14_i_seq;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+--------------------
sequence_name | so14_i_seq
last_value    | 1
start_value   | 1
increment_by  | 1
max_value     | 9223372036854775807
min_value     | 1
cache_value   | 1
log_cnt       | 0
is_cycled     | f
is_called     | f

t=# ALTER SEQUENCE so14_i_seq START WITH 1000;
ALTER SEQUENCE
t=# select * from so14_i_seq;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+--------------------
sequence_name | so14_i_seq
last_value    | 1
start_value   | 1000
increment_by  | 1
max_value     | 9223372036854775807
min_value     | 1
cache_value   | 1
log_cnt       | 0
is_cycled     | f
is_called     | f

t=# insert into so14 values(DEFAULT);
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so14 values(DEFAULT);
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from so14_i_seq;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+--------------------
sequence_name | so14_i_seq
last_value    | 2
start_value   | 1000
increment_by  | 1
max_value     | 9223372036854775807
min_value     | 1
cache_value   | 1
log_cnt       | 31
is_cycled     | f
is_called     | t

t=# select * from so14;
-[ RECORD 1 ]
i | 1
-[ RECORD 2 ]
i | 2

t=# ALTER SEQUENCE so14_i_seq RESTART WITH 1000;
ALTER SEQUENCE
t=# insert into so14 values(DEFAULT);
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from so14;
-[ RECORD 1 ]
i | 1
-[ RECORD 2 ]
i | 2
-[ RECORD 3 ]
i | 1000

t=# select * from so14_i_seq ;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+--------------------
sequence_name | so14_i_seq
last_value    | 1000
start_value   | 1000
increment_by  | 1
max_value     | 9223372036854775807
min_value     | 1
cache_value   | 1
log_cnt       | 32
is_cycled     | f
is_called     | t

t=#
```

Comment: I already have records in the `orders` table, where I do not change the `id`. Thus for the already established relation I'm not changing the `order_id`? I don't touch nothing

Answer (score 0):

To synchronize record you have to increase order_id in associated table.

Increasing id is not a good idea. But for solution you can do it like below.

Create migration and write this code

```
def change
  AssociatedModel.all.each do |associated_object|
    associated_object.order_id = associated_object.order_id + 1000
    associated_object.save(validate: false)
  end
end
```